# How to extend express request and response interfaces?

Tags: typescript, express, extends

I want to extend express `Request` and `Response` interfaces, i do it like this:

```
import express from 'express';

interface ResponseBody<T = any> {
    data?: T;
    error?: string;
}

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        export interface Request<T = any> extends express.Request {
            body: T;
        }

        export interface Response extends express.Response {
            json: (body?: ResponseBody) => this;
        }
    }
}
```

In my code i can access `req.body` and `res.json` with no errors, but when i'm trying to access other properties of `express.Request` or `express.Response` (e.g. `req.params`), i get an error in VS Code that this property doesn't exist in `Express.Request` or `Express.Response` type, although my interfaces extend original `Request` and `Response` types.

Why i'm not able to use `express.Request` and `express.Response` properties?